# Why summation and integrate give different results?

Tags: python, sympy

I think I am misunderstanding something. I think that printed results of this code snippet must be equal, but they are not:

```
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
summation = sympy.summation(sympy.exp(-x), (x, 0, sympy.oo))
print(summation)  # 1/(-exp(-1) + 1)
integration = sympy.integrate(sympy.exp(-x), (x, 0, sympy.oo))
print(integration)  # 1
```

Can you explain the difference between `summation` and `integrate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy's `summation` function sums the expression with the integers in the given range replacing the variable:

```
summation(sympy.exp(-x), (x, 0, sympy.oo))
```

Is equivalent to

```
exp(0) + exp(-1) + exp(-2) + ...
```

Which is approximately equal to:

```
1      + 0.37    + 0.14    + ...
```

Integration is a different function, which can be interpreted as calculating the area bounded by the curve generated by the function and the x axis (shaded in orange here):

[image]

Comment: Oh, I forgot that summation goes over integers only... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong.

If you notice the summation is a sum of geometric sequence, you will find it to be different to integration.

Summation:

```
sum exp(-x)
= sum exp(-1)^x
= exp(-1)^0 / (1 - exp(-1))
= 1 / (1 - exp(-1))
```

Integration:

```
int exp(-x) dx
= - [ exp(-x) ]
= - [ exp(-infinity) - exp(0) ]
= - [ 0 - 1 ]
= 1
```

Sorry. StackOverflow do not do LaTeX.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know what is `sum of geometric sequence`, can you explain this?

Comment: added algebraic derivation

Comment: Still can't understand the part where you describe summation derivation... Why `sum exp(-1)^x` turns to `exp(-1)^0 / (1 - exp(-1))`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series
formula section, the paragraph starts with "As n goes to infinity"

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. Hope you don't worry about accepting another answer, because it points for the root of the problem: I forgot that summation goes over integers only, that's why I thought the results must be equal.